# Display values that are out of scope in addition to in scope

Tags: sql, reporting-services

So I have a complex situation.

I have a 3 tables:

**Product**

| Resource Name | Resource Type |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | Bold |
| E2 | Crema |
| C2 | Bold |
| C3 | Bold |

**Purchase_History**

| Resource Name | Qty | Cust ID | Date | Batch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 7 | 123 | Jun 1 | 324 |
| C1 | 7 | 222 | Jun 10 | 324 |
| C1 | 7 | 333 | Jun 11 | 4BZ |
| C1 | 7 | 124 | Jun 11 | 4BZ |
| C1 | 7 | 125 | Jun 11 | 324 |
| C1 | 7 | 111 | Jun 21 | 324 |
| C2 | 7 | 55 | Jun 22 | A22 |
| C2 | 7 | 1 | Jun 24 | A22 |

**Inventory**

| Resource Name | Available | Qty | Batch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 1 | 40 | 324 |
| C2 | 1 | 50 | 3GC |
| C1 | 2 | 0 | 4BZ |
| C2 | 1 | 99 | A22 |
| E2 | 1 | 99 | B22 |
| E2 | 2 | 0 | C22 |

So I've created a query as below:

```
Select 
p.resourcename
, ph.cust_id
, ph.batch
, case when i.available=1 then 'Yes' when i.available=2 then 'no' else ''end 'In Stock'
from product p
join purchase_history ph on ph.resource_name=p.resource_name
join inventory i on i.batch=ph.batch
where
ph.date >='Jun 1'
ph.date <='Jun 20'
```

I am getting the following:

| Resource Name | Cust Id | Batch | In Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 123 | 324 | Yes |
| C1 | 222 | 324 | Yes |
| C1 | 333 | 4BZ | No |
| C1 | 124 | 4BZ | No |
| C1 | 123 | 324 | Yes |

**What I would like to achieve is the below, where even though the last 2 batch and products are out of the range of transactions, we can still see them as below. I know this is a weird as but essentially the team wants to see what has been sold so far - within the date range - and all product availability status. Is this something achievable?**

| Resource Name | Cust Id | Batch | In Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 123 | 324 | Yes |
| C1 | 222 | 324 | Yes |
| C1 | 333 | 4BZ | No |
| C1 | 124 | 4BZ | No |
| C1 | 123 | 324 | Yes |
| C2 | n/a | 3GC | Yes |
| C2 | n/a | A22 | Yes |
| E2 | n/a | B22 | Yes |
| E2 | n/a | C22 | No |

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `left join` with purchase_history table:

```
Select 
p.resourcename
, ph.cust_id
, i.batch
, case when i.available=1 then 'Yes' when i.available=2 then 'no' else ''end 'In Stock'
from product p
join inventory i on i.resource_name=p.resource_name
left join purchase_history ph 
   on ph.resource_name=p.resource_name
   and i.batch=ph.batch
where
ph.date >='Jun 1' and ph.date <='Jun 20'
```

notice I changes the order of tables for better readability.

Comment: When I did that I just get null values

Comment: @lostcoder see updated answer , read batch from inventory instead of ph